# React Web App to React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I currently have a web app/api built using React, Node, Mongo & Express. I would also like to develop a react native clien that shares an API. Does having an existing react web client make the react-native mobile development any easier?  My biggest concern is authentication & authorization. Can you recommend any tutorials, frameworks, packages that could make it easier? As you can tell.. I am very new to development.

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be a comment not an answer. 
0
down vote
Why is your biggest concern Auth? You don't do AUTH on the client side. Doesn't your api already do that for you? It doesn't look like you looked into react-native at all by your question. You need to go through react-native tutorials on facebook and it will be clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the same backend that you use for your Web app, in React-Native.

You can even use the same packages like Axios or superagent.

React-Native's built in one is called Fetch().

You are simply pinging your RESTful backend from a different device.

React-Native code is not at all a one for one with React Code. They are very different and only follow the same architecture Design Principals.

This question has been asked many times.